# Iphone random crash issue

Tags: iphone, random, crash

Recently my iphone project comes to the end, but suffer some random crash during app running, and the call stack is always located in COCOA library, tough issue, don't know how to deal with it, for some cases I even suspect that is it apple's defect?

My questions.

1. For those random crash issue with few reproduce rate, how do you guys handle it? Any method to help to increase reproducible rate?
2. How to fix these crashes located in COCOA library? How to find more clues?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like and also what have you tried? Also you need to post what you get in Log when your app crashes.

Comment: App crash inconsistency happen due to memory issue most of the time... please analyze your code in instrument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app crashes in the COCOA code it does not mean that COCOA code is wrong - much more likely you fed some invalid data to it (for example nil where it does not supposed to be). If it's happening randomly there might be some multithreading concurrency behind or some of your objects become (auto)released too early, etc. You have to carefully analyze your code which operates with the COCOA classes where your crash happens, or try memory management debugging as suggested by other answerers.

Comment: How to make this kind of random crash easier to reproduce? Since reproduce is the first step to start fixing, anyone who has such experience please share, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no general recipe, based on the APIs you use it can depend on whatever you can and can not imagine. Finding the reproducibility (and thus the cause!) of a random crash is often more complicated then fixing the bug. Some ideas that can cause randomness: concurring threads modifying the same objects, objects autoreleased too early, event handlers released (or not created!) before the event providers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I don't start thinking that is COCOA the problem. It happens, but most cases the fault is ours.

When this kind of crashes happens the first thing to do is to run the static Analyzer, sometimes it's just a retain/release problem.
If you're using ARC, skip this part and start creating an Exception Breakpoint (search '[To add an exception breakpoint...](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html)' in linked guide). The exception breakpoint helps to have a more detailed crash log when an exception is thrown.

The third step is using Instruments, looking for waster memory, leaks and any other form of memory drain. How to use Instruments is deeply explained in a couple of WWDC videos.

Answer (score 0):

Enable NSZombie flag.
project(On Top LeftCorner of xcode)>Diagnostics>enable zombie objects

It will lte u know where ur code is crashing ..find it fix it